# link on a chrome bookmarks bar that opens more than one page at once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink

I want to have a link somewhere here

[image]

that will open more than one page at once.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do that, but it will be a little tricky.

First, I write javascript code that opens more than one page at once:

```
let links = [ 
    "https://google.com", 
    "https://yandex.com/" 
]; 

for (link of links) { 
    window.open(link, "_blank"); 
}
```

then I take this code and paste it to address line to remove new line characters and then add "javascript:" before it:

```
javascript:let links = [ "https://google.com", "https://yandex.com/" ]; for (link of links) { window.open(link, "_blank"); }
```

Then I add this instead of url to bookmarks bar link. If you use that link that way it will run the code on a page that you are currently using. And it will only open only the first link and block other `pop up windows`.

[image]

Then you go to a page, where you know that no pop up windows ever happen and click the link and allow pop up windows to pop up on that page. Refresh the page and click the link again and voila - lots of links open at once. But there is a but: the link will work only on the site where you allowed windows to pop up.